# How to setting feedback which should be automatically shown when a user responds to a question

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Form, I want to set feedback which should be automatically shown when a user responds to a question incorrectly. I found a class is QuizFeedback. But when I run an example of reference about QuizFeedback, I got 2 errors. An example code like this:

```js
var textItem = form.addTextItem().setTitle('Re-hydrating dried fruit is an example of what?');

var feedback = FormApp.createFeedback()
  .setDisplayText(
      "Good answer, but not quite right.  Please review chapter 4 before next time.")
  .addLink("http://wikipedia.com/osmosis");

textItem.setFeedbackForIncorrect(feedback);
```

The first error is `TypeError: Function setDisplayText not found in object FreebirdFeedbackBuilder`.

And the second error is `Method setFeedbackForIncorrect (FormApp.QuizFeedbackBuilder) not found.`

I see some another example in reference to a google form, function `setDisplayText` and method `setFeedbackForIncorrect` are used the same way.

There seems to be a change in the use of a function `setDisplayText` and a method `setFeedbackForIncorrect` that Google has yet to update.

Please let me know how to setting feedback with class QuizFeedback.

Comment: @ross It appears they got it from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/quiz-feedback), where the documentation is incorrect. The methods referenced in the code block do not exist and smart quotes are being used inside `.setDisplayText()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*It appears that the documentation provided by Google for these methods is incorrect!*

#### More Information:

[The `QuizFeedback` class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/quiz-feedback) has incorrect methods listed in the code blocks which is why you are receiving errors in your code.

The method `FormApp.createFeedback()` returns a `QuizFeedbackBuilder` object - an object which does not have a `setDisplayText()` method. This is the cause of the first error: `TypeError: Function setDisplayText not found in object FreebirdFeedbackBuilder`.

The second error, `Method setFeedbackForIncorrect (FormApp.QuizFeedbackBuilder) not found.`, has a similar origin - the `TextItem` Class does not have a method called `setFeedbackForIncorrect()`.

This *is* however a method of the `MultipleChoiceItem` class, a specific type of question item. Sadly, this is ***only*** a method of `MultipleChoiceItem` and so you can not set an incorrect message for `TextItem` responses.

You can however set general feedback, which shows regardless of whether the question was correct or not. This I have displayed in the code below. `QuizFeedbackBuilder` objects need to be built before adding them using the `.setGeneralFeedback()` method, however.

#### Fixes:

In order to fix this some code needs to be re-written:

```js
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var textItem = form.addTextItem().setTitle('Re-hydrating dried fruit is an example of what?');
  var feedback = FormApp.createFeedback().setText(
    "Good answer, but not quite right.  Please review chapter 4 before next time.")
  .addLink("http://wikipedia.com/osmosis");
  // the next line is the general feedback
  textItem.setGeneralFeedback(feedback.build());
```

I hope this is useful to you!

#### Google Documentation Issue:

I have taken the liberty of filing a report with Google for a documentation edit so that these errors are removed and the correct methods are reflected in their documentation.

#### References:

- [Class `FormApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app)

  - [`.createFeedback()` method of FormApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#createFeedback())
- [Class `QuizFeedbackBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/quiz-feedback-builder.html)

  - [`QuizFeedBackBuilder` methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/quiz-feedback-builder.html#methods)
- [Class `Form`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form)

  - [`.addTextItem()` method of `Form`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#addtextitem)
- [Class `TextItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item.html)

  - [`.setTitle()` method of `TextItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item.html#setTitle(String))
- [Class `MultipleChoiceItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item)

  - [`.setFeedbackForIncorrect()` method of `MultipleChoiceItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#setfeedbackforincorrectfeedback)

Comment: @Rafa_Guillermo I am having a lot of difficulties because of the inaccuracy and details of the documents. And these answer as your answer is really awesome for me. And I still have 2 issues with google apps script. I hope you will see and comment on these 2 issues after I post them. :)